# How to search the file content in a directory for a certain pattern then return (redirect) the filename to another file?

Tags: command-line, bash

I want to perform the following task using a bash command:

find all files in `/etc` that contain either the string "10.17.1" or "130.236.189" and output the filenames to another file.

I'm trying to do this using `egrep`.

Comment: Read `man egrep`; Read `man 7 regex`;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use

```
sudo egrep -rl '(10\.17\.1|130\.236\.189)' /etc > newfile
```

#### Notes

- You need `sudo` to see some files here.
- `-l` print only filenames, not the matching lines
- `-r` recursive search. Remove if you only want to check files in the top level
- `\.` match literal `.`; without escaping, `.` matches any character.
- `a|b` match `a` or `b`. The parentheses are superfluous in this example because there is nothing else in the regex. `'foo|bar'` matches `foo` or `bar` just as well as `'(foo|bar)'`. But I included them because I think it's good practice: the parentheses define the area to start/stop alternating, for example `'foo bar|baz'` matches `foo bar` or `baz`, whereas `'foo (bar|baz)'` matches `foo bar` or `foo baz`.

Comment: The periods should be escaped else they will match any single character I think? Or use `-F` to make a string match.